# array_merge removes a empty string

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

There's a thing that I don't understand when I use array_merge() :

```
$defaultOptions = [
        'active' => null,
        'activeClass' => 'active',
        'wrapper' => [
            'attributes' => null,
            'templateVars' => null
        ],
        'item' => [
            'hasChildrenClass' => '', // this disappears after array_merge
            'attributes' => null,
            'linkAttrs' => null,
            'templateVars' => null
        ]
    ];

    $options = [
        'active' => [5,3],
        'item' => [
            'attributes' => ['class' => 'test']
        ]
    ];

$options = array_merge($defaultOptions, $options);
```

The result of $options is

```
[
      'active' => [
        (int) 0 => (int) 5,
        (int) 1 => (int) 3,
      ],
      'activeClass' => 'active',
      'wrapper' => [
        'attributes' => null,
        'templateVars' => null,
      ],
      'item' => [
        'attributes' => [
          'class' => 'test',
        ],
      ],
    ]
```

I don't understand why $options['item']['hasChildrenClass'] disappeared in my result ?

Comment: you replace the entire `item` in the initial `$defaultOptions` with that given in the new `$options`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `array_merge()` if the arrays have the same string keys, then values from the later arrays will overwrite the previous one. If the arrays have numeric keys, then values from the later arrays will appended with previous one. **If the arrays contain `null` or `empty` values, this value will be skipped and removed from the merged array.**

[Read more at php.net manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still a bit confused, what is the best way to merge options for that type of array ? array_replace_recursive ?